# Drupal custom page template based on the title of the page

Tags: theming

I have the following page:

```
About us
```

Whose path is:

```
site.com/node/6
```

Theme suggestions for the template files are:

```
page--node--6.tpl.php
page--node.tpl.php
```

You should already know that it is too weird to create custom template files based on the node's id, thus I like to have my custom page template based on the page's title (of course, converted to machine name, for instance "About us" to be "about-s"). What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried Context or Panels modules. you can set displays of different pages based on different criteria.

Comment: I have them installed. You mean it is not possible by default in Drupal?

Comment: Maybe somebody else can answer that. I don't bother going the template route with those modules around. I mainly use Panels.

Comment: Correct @Mostafa, there's no default theme hook suggestions for the page template based on a node alias - just for the internal path (eg node/1). Given that the node id is far less ephemeral than the title, using that method would usually be preferred. Your "you should already know that it's too weird...based on the node id" suggestion is incorrect in my opinion

Comment: With title I mean a GUID in String than in vague Integer.

Comment: That's a terrible idea @Mostafa - an alias/title is **not** a GUID. It can be changed, so by definition that doesn't make sense. Not to mention that node titles are not unique. URL slugs are for humans, not computers, so when you're talking to a computer (ie naming a template file), you should use a proper and reliable identifier. Which in this case is the node id.

Comment: well, with GUID, you are right. In many frameworks we use a master template, and then for a certain page, like "about us", you would make another template called something like "about-us.tpl". Now, in Drupal, due to automatic scanning for templates, it should have permitted unique-names, machine-names generated/suggested by Drupal itself. For a front-end developer, it is too vague to search around for about-us page and discern it by seeing page--node--6.tpl.php file. Why do you defend it? There should be, must be, better to be, is necessary to have human-readable names for the template files.

Comment: Yes it's possible (see the answer); but it's definitely not necessary, hence its absence from core. You have a non-standard requirement to address template files by their URL alias or node title (I'm not 100% sure which you're after), so you'll need to code that yourself. The very fact that node titles are not unique should be enough to explain why it's not possible to do this, unless you also do something _else_ to mandate that node titles can't be duplicated. Drupal doesn't have the same constraint out of the box, so the feature you're looking for can't exist without extra work

Comment: As an aside, I'm defending it because given the nature of content in Drupal core, it would be illogical for these template suggestions to already exist. Just to be clear, I'm not suggesting for a moment that your requirement isn't a valid one (me thinking it's not the best idea is irrelevant), I'm just trying to explain why you won't find what you're looking for without jumping through some hoops

Comment: I do not necessarily stick to node's title, an extra field for unique_name or machine_name should suffice. You see famous modules such as Context already follow named GUID, than numeric ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is an optimal solution at all, because node titles can easily be changed (and duplicated), but here you go:

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  // This assumes that you are using Pathauto for generating clean URLs.
  // Get the "clean" title.
  $title = pathauto_cleanstring($vars['node']->title);
  // Replace all dashes with underscores. This is necessary for recognizing the
  // template filenames.
  $title = str_replace('-', '_', $title);
  // Add new template variation.
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $title;
}
```

Note: to make this bulletproof for different languages, alphabets and special characters, make sure you have the [Transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) module installed and set to transliterate strings prior to creating URL aliases. This way if a node title has non-standard character (e.g. `Č`) it will be transliterated to Latin alphabet (in this case `C`).

Comment: Instead of using pathauto function, I'd suggest to use Drupal's core function: `drupal_clean_css_identifier()` https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_clean_css_identifier/7 You could consider updating your answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The only downside to using Pathauto's function is that you need to have Pathauto installed, which most of the sites already do. `drupal_clean_css_identifier()` also does not transliterate the characters, so you would need another function call to clean the output. I can update it for future reference, but I believe the Pathauto approach makes more sense, because that's the module that will generate your URLs anyway, and it's shorter.

Comment: @Alexar that's not necessarily  correct - if you were creating a CSS class, then sure, but in this case you need the URL alias. Since path auto produces that alias, you should use its functions to reproduce the clean string (I'm assuming path auto installed, I've yet to come across a site where it isn't)

Comment: After testing this, I don't think `drupal_clean_css_identifier` is a viable solution anymore because it does not make the string lowercase, and there could be other edge cases (two spaces are converted to `--` for example) where this will provide quirky results. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Topsitemakers I agree that transliteration is totally helpful. Also I can see that `drupal_clean_css_identifier()` is not doing `strtolower` and I figured `drupal_html_class()` is the right one. But I would argue the assumption of having pathauto installed. Given all these, I would do something like this `$title = module_exists('pathauto') ? pathauto_cleanstring($title) : drupal_html_class($title);`

Comment: @Alexar You shouldn't use a function designed for preparing html classes or identifiers to prepare a filename. `drupal_html_class()` and `drupal_clean_css_identifier()` are not appropriate for this

Comment: @Clive I would suggest you first read w3 standards for naming conventions for CSS class names (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters), checkout ISO 10646 (http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/utf8-t1.html), understand what actually file name is (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename) and what are invalid characters in different operating systems (https://support.filetransporter.com/article/AA-00410). It is totally safe to use `drupal_clean_css_identifier()` to sanitize file names or you need to support your claim by providing references.

Comment: @Alexar no need to try to be condescending, please keep it civil. I just disagree with you; you can hammer in a nail with a screwdriver, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @Clive no worries mate. I was challenging you to convince me "why not?" when you say "you shouldn't". This way we learn, we fix ourselves if we are wrong and will leave other readers with valuable arguments and countable decisions. easy.

Comment: @Topsitemakers thanks for your comment it worked with me :)